# iphone - sign url request with X.509 Certificate

Tags: iphone, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I am trying to port what I have done in .NET to the iphone. Basically I am trying to use an API to communicate with a server. The API requires mutual authentication through a X.509 certificate.

I did manage to make this work with .NET (which was quite easy), however it's note clear with the iPhone.

Did somebody do this before and could show me some code I can start with?

Thanks!

edit1: I am using the Apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW8) to go further. I am now stuck at the point where SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult) would return kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure. It does not seem possible on the iPhone to get any more detail about the failure.

I created a self-signed certificate from the Keychain Access. Any idea how the certificate needs to be "setup" to pass the SecTrustEvaluate test?